# Sub-string extraction using regexp and sed in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

In a bash script, I would like to extract sub-string of the form `key=[value]`, so that I can get the `value` in a variable by specifying the corresponding`key`.

For instance, given this variable `txt`:

```
txt="something... key=[value] number=[0.42] ...other things... text=[foo] etc"
```

I would like to extract `value` for `key`, `0.42` for `number`, `foo` for `text` ... and empty string  for missing keys.

I tried this command, to extract `value`:

```
echo "$txt" | sed 's/^*key=\[[*]\]*/\1/'
```

If I understood well, the command `sed "s/regexp/replacement/"` try to match here the following regexp:

`^` the beginning of the line

`*` anything

`key=\[` the beginning of what I want to find

`[*^\[]` match anything, except character `[`

`\]` the end of what I want to find

`*` anything

`$` the end of the line

and replace it with what has been matched (due to `\1`).

But I am missing something since I get the following error message :
**sed: -e expression #1, char 27: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS**

I also tried this, without using `\1`:

```
echo "$txt" | sed 's/^*key=\[[*]\]*/TEST/'
```

But the regex failed to match and all the string of `txt` is returned...

Comment: You are mixing up `globs` and `regexes`. With a glob, `*` means `any character, any time`. With regexes, it is only a quantifier (any amount of time), but you still have to specify which pattern is repeated. The equivalent in regex is `.*`. [This website](https://regex101.com/) is a good tool to test your regexes.

Comment: Also, there are lots of other basic errors in your regex. Consider trying the website I linked in my previous comment to learn the regex syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` doesn't match any string. `*` is a quantifier which says "the previous could be repeated zero or more times". You need a regex for sed, not a wildcard pattern:

```
sed 's/.*key=\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/'
```

- `\(...\)` are needed to create a capture group, referenced as `\1` (because it's the first such group)
- `[^]]*` means "anything but `]` zero or more times", so it matches the string inside square brackets